duvida php utilizando conceito padrao mvc (caminho relativo)
Boa tarde
Estou fazendo curso técnico de desenvolvimento de sistemas web.
Como projeto final estamos desenvolvendo um sistema web em html, css, php e mysql aplicando o conceito de padrão MVC.
Já desenvolvemos as camadas VIEW e MODEL, e agora estamos começando a desenvolver a camada CONTROLLER.
Os arquivos estão conforme a imagem
Estrutura dos arquivos
(caminho completo do projeto: root/htdocs/EAD_TEC/DS_III/Ag_11_12_13)
Iniciando o arquivo index.php o mesmo apenas executa o código abaixo
Codigo php da pagina index
O arquivo navegação.php tem o seguinte código
codigo do arquivo navegacao.php
Sempre que o index.php é iniciado o arquivo navegação redireciona para a pagina login
Pagina de login
A pagina login.php possui um formulário que em seu atributo action redireciona para o arquivo navegação novamente
caminho para o arquivo navegacao.php
Temos dentro do formulário o botão btnPrimeiroAcesso que quando clicado e será passado como parâmetro pelo método post para o arquivo navegação.php
botao primeiroAcesso
Que pela linha de codigo deveria abrir a pagina primeiroAcesso.php dentro da pasta View
Codigo para execulcao do arquivo primeiroAcesso.php
Ao invés de abrir a pagina, é retornado o erro
mensagem de erro do servidor
Pela logica o caminho esta correto pois do arquivo navegação dentro da pasta controller, voltaria um diretório, depois entraria na pasta view e excutaria a pagina primerioacesso.php.
Como mostrado na estrutura de arquivos, o projeto esta dentro de uma pasta chamada Ag_11_12_13 e esta pasta esta dentro da pasta raiz do servidor que estou utilizando para testes (usbWebserver)
Se eu pegar as pastas e arquivos do projeto e colocar direto na pasta root (raiz do servidor) as direcionamentos do arquivo navegação funcionam corretamente. O erro só acontece se as pastas e arquivos do projeto estiverem dentro que uma subpasta da raiz do servidor.
Minha duvida é, porque isso ocorre sendo que o caminho esta especificado corretamente? Tem como resolver?
Sei que existem outra formas de aplicar o mvc, e que são mais eficientes e melhores, porem eu quero entender o porque do erro e se existe a possibilidade de resolver.

Evite repetir perguntas, siga as orientações fornecidades na pergunta original. Se precisar comentar, faça na pergunta original. Nota: NÃO usar imagens para códigos e logs. Agradecemos a compreensão.
